# Style a <tr> tag depending on the content of the responding <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I import a Table from a Postgres DB to the Website and if i request the attribute table, for one item, there are a lot of attributes that show: NULL, (NULL) or false, and i dont need those in my table, because they dont add extra information for the user.

```
<tr>
    <th>Anrede</th>
    <td>(NULL)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Postleitzahl</th>
    <td>NULL</td>
<tr>
```

My idea now is to look what stands in `<td>...</td>` and depending of that to set the style of `<tr>` to "display:none". 
But im not sure how to do so, if i have to write a JS function or if i just can use html and css?

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS, so you would probably need javascript. With jquery you could something like this: `$('td:contains("NULL"), td:contains("false"),').parent().hide();`, but you didn't tag this question with jquery, but I am sure you can do something similar with vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1):

via javascript, you can use `textContent` to check td's content:

```js
for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('#test td')) {
  if ( el.textContent == '(NULL)' || el.textContent =='NULL') {
    el.parentNode.style.display="none"
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <th>Anrede</th>
    <td>(NULL)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Postleitzahl</th>
    <td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Anrede</th>
    <td>(NULL)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Postleitzahl</th>
    <td> See Us </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWwPOvw

Answer (score 0):

@nunkuat
 actually td stands for table data. And it is usually used to define a standard data cell in a table that contains certain data.
and mainly td elements shud be enclosed within tr tags.
now for example check this code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 0.5px #333 solid;">First table cell</td>
    <td style="border: 0.5px #333 solid;">Second table cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here td is assigned to some values 
similarly td is mandatory sort even if it is assigned it with values or even if it is assigned to null.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with their markup. putting a `<th>` nested inside a `<tr>` is 100% valid. This also doesn't answer the question what so ever

Comment: oh well then i apologise @zgood i might have misunderstood the question thanks for making me realise it